# Model comparison: what to do when reduced model doesn't converge?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, model-selection, model-comparison, glmmtmb

This is a general question about how to do hypothesis testing via model comparison:

I want to test the significance of several different predictors in a data set using model comparison. After a lot of tweaking and rethinking I have a full model that seems to be pretty much the minimum complexity that fits well and is sensible (a zero-inflated quasi-Poisson mixed effects model fit using glmmTMB).

My problem is that when I try to test the significance of predictors by comparing the full model to models with one term of interest removed, the reduced models sometimes won't converge so can't be formally compared. In this case I can't adjust the model parameters because the reduced model has to be the same as the full model minus the one term being tested.

In general, what would you do in this situation? Do I just have to adjust both the full and reduced models so that both will converge? That would seem a bit odd to me though, since my full model as it currently stands is based on how I think the data-generating process actually works. It would be strange to change this just in order to test a secondary hypothesis.